# Only same data is got several times

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel and print out it.I wrote like

```
files = glob.glob('./data/*.xlsx')

for x in files:
    if "$" not in x:
      print(x)
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
    ('user_id', 0, 4),
    ('name', 0, 5),
    ('nationality', 1, 4),
    ('domitory', 1, 5),
    ('group', 1, 6),
      ]
      dict_data = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
         try:
            dict_data[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
         except IndexError:
            dict_data[key] = None

         print(dict_data)
```

So,I got a result like

```
OrderedDict([('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)], [('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)], [('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)])
```

Excel is
[image: excel]

So I really cannot understand why I got only one data several times.I wanna get all data only 1 time each data.How can I fix this?I do not think indent is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need fixed indent:

```
for key, rowy, colx in cells:
    try:
        dict_data[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
    except IndexError:
        dict_data[key] = None
# <--- move left print
print(dict_data)
```